# Extrude horizontally

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, materials, extrude

[image]
I couldn't find a way to extrude horizentally like the video i've tried it with e but it extrudes verically or they all go into the same way.

https://youtu.be/8daiSGVfp9g
0:30

Comment: Did you set your *Transform Pivot Point* (the second box from the right on the middle top) to *Individual Origins* ???

Answer (score 3):

With your vertices selected in edit mode

[image]

press E S and move your cursor.

[image]

Comment: You can also use shift-z when scaling to constrain only to Z axis